# Getting the Gracenote gem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, gracenote

Attempting to use the Gracenote gem to hit the web api - registers fine but the query times out - anyone out there able to use this successfully?

Answer (score 3):

I've also seen this quite a bit.

<strike>There's a chance this is tied to a threaded timeout bug with Net:HTTP. I've switched my local version of the gem over to HTTParty and am no longer seeing this issue.</strike>

I may have spoken too soon - still seeing the timeouts. Would be great to see someone from Gracenote comment on timeout policies.

**Update** To further add to this, I've executed the pygn repo and am not seeing any timeouts. This further leads to a bug the ruby version's HTTP lib.

** **Answer** ** I've updated the repo to use libcurl instead of Net::HTTP and it has fixed the problem. https://github.com/MattNewberry/gracenote